# Table border doubles when the site is hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table (1 Row, 1 Column) with a single border on my webpage. But when the site is hosted in IIS I get double border lines. What could be the cause?

Comment: You're probably zoomed in the browser, or maybe your CSS is cached. Ctrl+F5 should reload everything.

Comment: I hosted this on two different machines and still.

Comment: I dont understand this site. If people dont have answers for your question they keep rating you down and editing your post whereas all you need is help. I get discouraged

Comment: It would help if you posted enough information for others to be able to reproduce your problem. When you see the single border, we know it's not on IIS, but you haven't told us where it *is* -- is it a local file, is it hosted on Apache, what? Which browser(s) are you using when you see the problem? Can you post a minimal HTML snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Have a look at what kind of questions you should be asking here: http://stackoverflow.com/help If you take the time to formulate the question well, **and provide code**, it will be much easier for others to figure out what you mean.